# Inverse function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function $h$ is defined by $h:x\rightarrow 2-\frac{a}{x}$, where $x\neq 0$ and $a$ is a constant. Given $\frac{1}{2}h^2(2)+h^{-1}(-1)=-1$, find the possible values of $a$.

Can someone give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: Well do you know what $h^{-1}$ is?

Comment: Yup. I know the inverse of h.

Comment: Then have you plugged in the values to $h^{-1}$ and $h^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for this problem.  I was not familiar with the notation $h^2(x)=h(h(x))$, but this is clearly what must be meant in this problem since interpreting $h^2(x)=(h(x))^2$, yields no real solutions.

If $h(x)=2-\frac{a}{x}$, then we can solve for $h^{-1}(x)$ in the following manner.

$x=2-\frac{a}{h^{-1}(x)} \Rightarrow x-2=-\frac{a}{h^{-1}(x)} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x-2}=-\frac{h^{-1}(x)}{a} \Rightarrow -\frac{a}{x-2}=h^{-1}(x)=\frac{a}{2-x}$

Therefore $h^{-1}(-1)=\frac{a}{3}$

Now if we interpret $h^2(x)$ to mean $h(h(x))$, then $$h^2(x)=h(2-\frac{a}{x})=2-\frac{a}{2-\frac{a}{x}}=2-\frac{a}{\frac{2x-a}{x}}=2-\frac{ax}{2x-a}=\frac{4x-2a-ax}{2x-a}$$

So that $\frac{1}{2}h^2(2)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{8-2a-2a}{4-a}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{8-4a}{4-a}=\frac{4-2a}{4-a}$

Plugging these values into your equation yields

$$\frac{4-2a}{4-a}+\frac{a}{3}=-1 \Rightarrow \frac{12-6a+4a-a^2}{12-3a}=-1 \Rightarrow 12-2a-a^2=3a-12$$

Bringing everything to one side gives us the following quadratic equation

$$a^2+5a-24=0$$

This equation is factorable and gives us $(a+8)(a-3)=0 \Rightarrow a=3$ and $a=-8$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, find the inverse function $h^{-1}$. I.e. let $y=2-a/x$ and hence $h^{-1}$ is defined as

\begin{align}x=2-\frac{a}{y} \ \ & \Longrightarrow \ \ \frac{a}{y}=2-x\\
&\Longrightarrow y=\frac{a}{2-x}.
\end{align}
Now, $h(2)=2-a/2$ and $h^{-1}(-1)=a/3$. You should be able to continue from here and get a quadratic equation in $a$.

**Edit**. Here is some extra help. Your equation can be evaluated with the information above:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}h^2(2)+h^{-1}(-1)&=\frac{1}{2}(h(2))^2+h^{-1}(-1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(2-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{a}{3}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't be $y=\frac{2-a}{x}$? @J.Marshall

Comment: I've added an extra step to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Why not hh(2)??

Comment: I assume that you're thinking that $h^2(2)=hh(2)$, but this is incorrect. $h^2(2)$ is just a shorthand notation for $(h(2))^2$.

Comment: I still can't find the a. :(

Comment: @J.Marshall $h^2(2)$ is not necessarily $(h(2))^2$ -- it really depends on the text. (If that were the case, how can you be sure that $h^{-1}(-1)$ is not a short for $(h(-1))^{-1}$?) Most texts I have seen reserve your usage for trig functions only ($\sin^2(x)$, for instance).

Comment: You are correct, that was an oversight on my part.

Comment: $h(2) = 2-a/2$, not $2-2/a.$

Comment: Woops. My mistake, thank you.